# Create a new Map <String, List<String>> with selective elements from another Map <String, List<String>>

Tags: java, regex, collections, groovy

Am trying to create a new `Map <String, List<String>> headErrors` with selective elements from another `Map <String, List<String>> invoiceErrorLines`

```
invoiceErrorLines = ['1660277':['Line : 1 Invoice does not foot Reported', 'Line : 2 MATH ERROR'], 
                    '1660278':['Line : 5 Invoice does not foot Reported', 'cl_id is a required field'], 
                    '1660279':['Line : 7 could not parse date ', 'File Error : The file doesnt have delimiter'], 
                    '1660280':['Line : 9 Invoice error']]
def regex = "^Line\\s(?:(\\d+)\\s)?\\s*:\\s+(\\d+)?.+"
def headErrors = invoiceErrorLines.each{ inv ->
   inv.value.findAll{it.contains('Invoice does not foot Reported') || !(it ==~ regex) }.groupBy{inv.key} 
}
```

New Map should contain invoice numbers as key and its corresponding error messages which doesnt match `regex = "^Line\\s(?:(\\d+)\\s)?\\s*:\\s+(\\d+)?.+"` but contains `Invoice does not foot Reported`

When I print `headErrors` am seeing the same map as `invoiceErrorLines` but
am expecting the `headErrors` as below

```
headErrors = ['1660277':['Line : 1 Invoice does not foot Reported'], 
              '1660278':['Line : 5 Invoice does not foot Reported', 'cl_id is a required field'], 
              '1660279':['File Error : The file doesnt have delimiter'] 
             ]
```

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With

```
def headErrors = invoiceErrorLines.collectEntries{ key, value ->
   value.findAll{ it.contains('Invoice does not foot Reported') || !(it ==~ regex) }.groupBy{ key }
}
```

it yields

```
[1660277:[Line : 1 Invoice does not foot Reported], 1660278:[Line : 5 Invoice does not foot Reported, cl_id is a required field], 1660279:[File Error : The file doesnt have delimiter]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I appreciate it. Can you also help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29570648/java-8-find-and-replace-matching-strings

Comment: can you please help me solving this problem?
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47717505/groovy-create-a-map-with-jax-b-objects-specific-attributes